# Waiting for meteor cursor in method

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a large aggrogate query that required me to pass "allowDiskUse: true" as an option.  This would not work with the aggegate as described here:
https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-aggregate/issues/11

My meteor method is defined here.  When I call the method I need to wait for ondata to complete before anything is returned to the client, but nothing I try allows me to get that data in a safe way up to the front end.

```
Meteor.methods({
  'getSummary': function (dept,startDate,endDate,filterType) {

         f = myQuery(startdate,enddate,dayFinalGroup);   
        f.on("data", Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(row) {
//load an array or something here to return
            }));
            f.once("end", Meteor.bindEnvironment(function() {
                // tidy up, in my case end the stream

            }));


    //here I'd return the array loaded

  },

});
```

This is my front end.

```
Meteor.call(
    'getSummary',0,Session.get('start_date'),Session.get('end_date'),1,
    function(error, result){
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        } else {        
                Session.set('sumTotals',result);
        }
    }
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally Got it.  I utilized wrapSync

```
 'getSummary': function (dept,startDate,endDate,filterType) {
         console.log(dept);
         console.log(startDate);
         console.log(endDate);
         console.log(filterType);
         var startdate = new Date(startDate);
         var enddate = new Date(endDate);
         var arr = [];
         f = myQuery(startdate,enddate,dayFinalGroup);   

         var fetchCursor = Meteor.wrapAsync(function fetchCursor (cursor, cb) {

                        cursor.each(function (err, doc) {
                        if (err) return cb(err);
                        if (!doc) return cb(null, { done: true }); // no more documents

                        arr.push(doc);
                        });
        });


     var myData = fetchCursor(f);




        return arr;
```

Comment: Don't forget a `this.unblock()` in your method. See https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/using-unblock-and-defer-in-methods